# Placing plotly graphics into a leaflet

Tags: python, user-interface, plotly, mapping

Im using the Plotly library for an interactive map in python. However, when you use this library it opens it up in chrome when I want to place the figure onto a leaflet to be used in TKinter

```
from tkinter import *
import csv
import sys

import plotly.graph_objects as go
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
mapbox_access_token = "pk.eyJ1IjoiY21jY3Vza2VyMTMyMiIsImEiOiJja254YjA5emEwb21rMnB0Z3Nib285OGNkIn0.PL7Nx-Q1XgSO5PBSdI2w2Q"

fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(
        lat=['54.1533'],
        lon=['-6.0663'],
        mode='markers',
        marker=go.scattermapbox.Marker(
            size=14
        ),
        text=['Mournes'],
    ))

fig.update_layout(
    hovermode='closest',
    mapbox=dict(
        accesstoken=mapbox_access_token,
        bearing=0,
        center=go.layout.mapbox.Center(
            lat=54,
            lon=-6
        ),
        pitch=0,
        zoom=9
    )
)
fig.show()
f = fig
```

Comment: It doesn't look like the problem has anything to do with `tkinter` so please remove that tag.

Comment: `plotly` generates HTML with JavaScript - and it doesn't use `matplotlib` for this - so `FigureCanvasTkAgg` is useless. Probably `plotly` doesn't have method to use `matplot` to render it in `tkinter`. You can use it only in other direction - in `matplotlib` you can use `plotly` to generate HTML instead of display it in Tkinter. To display `plotly` you would need some widget which can display HTML but standard HTML widget in tkinter has big problem with CSS and it can't run JavaScript.

Comment: Maybe with external module like [cefpython](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython) (Chrome Engine Framework) you could embed Chrome Engine inside `tkinter` and display HTML+JavaScript generated with `plotly`. Or maybe you should use `PyQT` which always had HTML widget - `WebKit` widget which later was used to build browser `Safari` and `Chrome`